# Concatenate pandas DataFrames on columns, similar to outer merge

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have 3 dataframes with dates on the first column of each. I would like to concat these dataframes but concating related with the row value of each. If the values match, add on the same row, otherwise, I would expect to have a NaN.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create the pandas DataFrame
df1 = pd.DataFrame(['2018-12-31','2019-09-30','2022-01-31'], columns = ['Date1'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(['2019-09-30','2022-02-28'], columns = ['Date2'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(['2019-09-30','2021-06-30','2021-11-30','2022-03-31'], columns = ['Date3'])

display(df1)
display(df2)
display(df3)

data = {'Date1': ['2018-12-31','2019-09-30',np.nan,np.nan,'2022-01-31',np.nan,np.nan],
        'Date2': [np.nan,'2019-09-30',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'2022-02-28',np.nan],
        'Date3': [np.nan,'2019-09-30','2021-06-30','2021-11-30',np.nan,np.nan,'2022-01-31']}

desired_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
desired_df
```

This is what I am trying to achieve.

|  | Date1 | Date2 | Date3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2018-12-31 | NaN | NaN |
| 1 | 2019-09-30 | 2019-09-30 | 2019-09-30 |
| 2 | NaN | NaN | 2021-06-30 |
| 3 | NaN | NaN | 2021-11-30 |
| 4 | 2022-01-31 | NaN | NaN |
| 5 | NaN | 2022-02-28 | NaN |
| 6 | NaN | NaN | 2022-01-31 |

My original idea was to used something like:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2,df3], axis=1, join="outer")
```

However, above will produce something like:

| Date1 | Date2 | Date3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-12-31 | 2019-09-30 | 2019-09-30 |
| 2019-09-30 | 2022-02-28 | 2021-06-30 |
| 2022-01-31 | NaN | 2021-11-30 |
| NaN | NaN | 2022-03-31 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could `set_index` with the Dates (by setting the `drop` parameter to False, we don't lose the column), then `concat` horizontally:

```
out = (pd.concat([df.set_index(f'Date{i+1}', drop=False) 
                 for i, df in enumerate([df1, df2, df3])], axis=1)
       .sort_index().reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
        Date1       Date2       Date3
0  2018-12-31         NaN         NaN
1  2019-09-30  2019-09-30  2019-09-30
2         NaN         NaN  2021-06-30
3         NaN         NaN  2021-11-30
4  2022-01-31         NaN         NaN
5         NaN  2022-02-28         NaN
6         NaN         NaN  2022-03-31
```